# GitLab CI execute deploy stage after one of multiple build stages is done

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, cd

I have four build stages, which are operated manually. What I'd like is to execute the deploy stage, after **one** build stage is finished. Right now my implementation only works when all four build stages are finished.

Use case: Dev klicks on the environment he wants to build. After build is done, it is deployed to the systems. Deploy should start automatically after build is finished

Q: Is there a way to execute the deploy stage after only **one** build is done?

My implementation of the build pipelines (simplified):

```
production:
  stage: env
  script:
    - echo build one
  when: manual
  allow_failure: false

production2:
  stage: env
  script: 
    - echo build two
  when: manual
  allow_failure: false

staging:
  stage: env
  script: 
    - echo build three
  when: manual
  allow_failure: false

staging2:
  stage: env
  script:
    - echo build four
  when: manual
  allow_failure: false
```

This is my deploy stage

```
build:
  stage: build
  needs: [production, production2, staging, staging2]
  when: on_success

  script:
    - echo do deploy stuff
```

Many thanks and I wish you a nice day

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this help?

```
build:
  stage: build
  needs:
    - job: production
      optional: true
    - job: production2
      optional: true
    - job: staging
      optional: true
    - job: staging2
      optional: true
  when: on_success
  script:
    - echo do deploy stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

So far I've only found a solution that works.

```
stages:
  - env
  - connections
  - build

production:
  stage: env
  script:
    - echo build one
  when: manual
  allow_failure: false

production2:
  stage: env
  script: 
    - echo build two
  when: manual
  allow_failure: false

staging:
  stage: env
  script: 
    - echo build three
  when: manual
  allow_failure: false

staging2:
  stage: env
  script:
    - echo build four
  when: manual
  allow_failure: false

# Connections 
  
run:build:production:
  extends: .build
  stage: connections
  needs:
    - job: production
    
run:build:production2:
  extends: .build
  stage: connections
  needs:
    - job: production2

run:build:staging:
  extends: .build
  stage: connections
  needs:
    - job: staging

run:build:staging2:
  extends: .build
  stage: connections
  needs:
    - job: staging2 

.build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo do deploy stuff
```